Dynamic controller in ASP.NET Web API
I need to add a controller dynamically to .NET Web API at application start, so based on configuration. The controller is located in separate assembly, and it could look like:
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("myget")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("myget/{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}

The project is under .NET Framework 4.6.2 without MVC.
How is it possible to make such a thing?
